# how to display the app_offline page when i deploy this projects in azure devops in iis?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, azure-devops, devops

my project is published successfully but I want to display the app_offline page when I deploy the project. I have created the app_offline.htm file and I don't know where this file is placed in a directory

**Root Directory**
[image: app_offline page]

Comment: Hi Muthu, Does below answer work? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Comment: yes, but I did not select the option "Take App Offline"  I'm using another one like package inside the deployment

Comment: Thanks for your reply and gladly to hear that you have resolved this issue using your solution. Do you mind sharing your solution under below Answer section? So it can help others if they have same issue in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable "**Take App Offline**" option in the [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops).
[image]
This option points that taking the Web App offline by placing an app_offline.htm file in the root directory of the Web App before the sync operation begins. The file will be removed after the sync operation completes successfully. So you need to place this file in the root directory of the Web App in your local physical path.

Answer (score 0):

**add these two items**
"copy files" app_offline.htm before deploying and the "delete files" item can be deleted after deployment is complete.[image: add file and delete]

Comment: Hi Muthu, Thanks for your sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could guide other community members who get the same issues, thank you.